# How to stop other response data with Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am doing options request data from server by using Nodejs,
but I don't know how to handle response data with delay in same request,
Here's the front code:

HTML(click to request data from server):

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="animalSpecies.species" ng-click="selectAnimal()" name="animal" value="Dog"/>Dog
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="animalSpecies.species" ng-click="selectAnimal()" name="animal" value="Cat"/>Cat
</label>
```

Angular:

```
function testCtrl($scope, $http) {
    var config;
    $scope.animalSpecies = {
        species: ""
    }
    $scope.selectAnimal = function () {
        config = {
            method: "GET",
            url: "/getanimal",
            params: {
                species: $scope.animalSpecies.species
            }
        }

        $http(config).then(
                function (res) {
                    console.log(res.data);
                }
        )

    }
}
```

Nodejs

```
app.get("/getanimal", function (req, res) {
    var species = req.query.species;
    if (species === "Dog") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            res.send({msg: "species is" + species});
        }, 1000)
    } else {
        res.send({msg: "species is" + species});
    }
})
```

When you click "Dog" option first and quickly click "Cat" option,
the "Cat"'s response data will first come out ,but finally the "Dog"'s
data will response a second later.(I do a setTimeout delay in Nodejs,but maybe 
other conditions like querying database callback delay or somehow)

What I want is just:Is there some way to stop server to response data or
I get what I want doing in frontend?

Comment: You can try and cancel your http request with AngularJS (using interceptors and/or palying witht timeouts and promises). You can find many examples on SO that show how to abort a pending/running http request.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to disable the control for the user if the first response hasn't come back yet.

Disable the input buttons when the user clicks one of them, and enable them on server response